# chrome.pageAction.show only works with timeout

Tags: google-chrome-extension, timeout, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a chrome extension that is supposed to show a page action icon whenever a PDF is loaded. To this end, I'm checking the content type, and if it equals `application/pdf`, I `chrome.pageAction.show(tabId)`. To my surprise, however, this

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) { 
    if (details.tabId >= 0) { 
      var header = getContentTypeFromHeaders(
        details.responseHeaders,
        'content-type'
      );
      global.tabToMimeType[details.tabId] = 
        header && header.value.split(';', 1)[0];
      if (global.tabToMimeType[details.tabId] === 'application/pdf') { 
        chrome.pageAction.show(details.tabId);
      }
    }
  },
  { 
    urls: ['*://*/*.pdf'],
    types: ['main_frame']
  },
  ['responseHeaders']
);
```

doesn't work. I can see the icon flashing up sometimes, but it's never persistent. If instead I replace

```
chrome.pageAction.show(details.tabId);
```

by

```
setTimeout(function() {
    chrome.pageAction.show(details.tabId);
}, 100);
```

it all comes out nicely. What is the explanation for this? Is there any more systematic way than waiting for 100 milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you try to show too early, before the navigation is processed by a tab.

So your icon shows up, THEN page transitions and the icon is wiped.

<del>Try moving your logic to `onResponseStarted` or even to `onCompleted`.</del>

Since even that is not enough, and it's hard to tie a `webRequest` event to a `tabs`/`webNavigation` event, you can either proceed with your approach or try and find another method of detecting PDFs with `tabs`/`webNavigation` API.

---

This quote from `webNavigation` docs shows what I mean:

> In general, the `webNavigation` events are closely related to the navigation state that is displayed in the UI, while the `webRequest` events correspond to the state of the network stack which is generally opaque to the user.

So `webRequest` events are not tied to the tab transition and can't be reliably used for showing a page action.